# uWSGI backtrace: segmentation fault

Tags: python, django, segmentation-fault, uwsgi

Weird uwsgi segmentation fault error on new server with Ubuntu 14.04 (old one was 12.04). Here the log:

```
!!! uWSGI process 12360 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 12360 ***
uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2e) [0x468a9e]
uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x21) [0x468e61]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36d40) [0x7f816fcc0d40]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1b90a8) [0x7f81702090a8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x177e97) [0x7f81701c7e97]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(_PyObject_GC_Malloc+0xcb) [0x7f81701c8acb]
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47) [0x7f8170138837]
uwsgi(python_call+0x11) [0x47b011]
uwsgi(uwsgi_request_wsgi+0x116) [0x47d206]
uwsgi(wsgi_req_recv+0x8e) [0x41e64e]
uwsgi(simple_loop_run+0xc4) [0x465084]
uwsgi(uwsgi_ignition+0x194) [0x4690b4]
*** end of backtrace ***
```

The uwsgi settings are largely the same (number of requests also ):

Old server with U12.04

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0 (64bit) on [Sun Feb 22 12:56:07 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 12 January 2014 18:02:18
os: Linux-3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:25:51 UTC 2013
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 8
your processes number limit is 256762
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
```

New server with U14.04

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Sun Feb 22 12:56:49 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 09 February 2015 11:16:35
os: Linux-3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 12
your processes number limit is 515009
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
```

What might cause the error? We are running django, postgres and nginx.

Comment: Did you change the machine, upgrade the VM or do a clean install?

Comment: Reinstall the UWSGI stuff. And make sure you reinstall all locally installed Python extensions.

Comment: We found the bug: a new version of xxtea for python caused the error. Thanks for your comments...